# need a condition to separate two json types

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, moodle

I want to condition for below if condition to if that response type is `[{\"id\":38,\"shortname\":\"sp\"}]`.

Here id and shortname are changing time to time.

```
public string ReturnResponseCourse(string response)
        {
            if ()//[{\"id\":38,\"shortname\":\"newuser30\"}]
            {
                string id = "";
                string shortname = "";
                var k = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(response);
                foreach (var a in k)
                {
                    id = (a["id"]);
                    shortname = (a["shortname"]);
                }

                return "Course id : " + id + ",Course short name : " + shortname;
            }
            else
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                dynamic blogObject = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(response);
                string errorcode = blogObject["errorcode"];
                string message = blogObject["message"];
                return responseCode + ", Error Code :" + errorcode + ", Error Message : " + message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: you can deserialize  first and then compare

Comment: Or parse json to `JObject` and check its properties

Comment: the problem is some times response returns json strings and some times it return json array.I want to check it is array or json string.@viveknuna @Pavel